# Suppose that $p$ and $q$ are two prime numbers such that $p+q^2$ is a perfect square.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, contest-math

Show that for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$, $p^2+q^n$ is never a perfect square.

We can suppose that there exists $n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $p^2+q^n=l^2$ with $l\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Moreover we know that there exists $k\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $p+q^2=k^2$.

So we deduce : $p=k^2-q^2=(k-q)(k+q)$.

As $p$ is a prime number and $(k-q)<(k+q)$ we can deduce that $p=k+q$.

Then $p^2 +q^n=(k+q)^2 + q^n= l^2$.

So $k^2 +2kq+ q^2 + q^n=l^2$.

Then I'm stuck to find a contradiction so maybe it is the wrong way to proceed ...

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Also $k-q=1$...

Comment: The title does not reflect the question.

Comment: This is not clear.  Is the title something we should assume to hold for the question in the body of the post?

Comment: @lulu The title is the assumption.

Comment: are p and q prime numbers?

Comment: @datonefaridze Indeed

Comment: Please edit to ask a complete question.  Include all the necessary assumptions in the body of the post.

Comment: As quick observations, if $q^n=(m+p)(m-p)$ we see that we must have $p+m=q^r$ and $m-p=q^s$.  subracting shows that $2p=q^s(q^{r-s}-1)$ so $q$ divides $2p$.  Thus $q$ is either $2$ or $p$.

Comment: @lulu Thanks but how do you get the contradiction if $q=2$ ?

Comment: There is not necessarily a contradiction when $q=2$, viz: $3^2+2^4=5^2$

Comment: When $q=2$  we have $2^n=(m+p)(m-p)$ so you need two powers of $2$ that differ by $2p$.  Just look for solutions to that.  You are lead to consider Mersenne primes, so it is unknown whether or not there are infinitely many solutions.

Comment: I should say:  we are ignoring your condition that $p+q^2=k^2$.  With $q=2$ that comes down to $p=k^2-4=(k+2)(k-2)$.  Since $p$ is prime we must have $k-2=1$ so $k=3$ and $p=5$.  or $k+2=1$, in which case $k=-1$ and $p=3$ so you only have to check two cases.

Comment: @lulu It's "or $k+2=p$" ?

Comment: No, I meant to consider two cases:  Either both factors are positive, in which case we have $k-2=1, k+2=p$ or both factors are negative, in which case you have $k+2=-1,k-2=-p$.  The first gives you $k=3, p=5$ and the second gives you $k=-3, p=5$, so either way you get $p=5$ as the only solution.